# Dynamic column name within select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a begginer with MySQL.

I have one simple table, where the column names are the names of the months. This table is called '**Tarif**'

I also have one function procedure which returns a varchar with the name of the month and, receive as input a datetime. This function is called '**getMonth**', and would work something like:

```
getMonth('2021-01-04')
and this returns: 'January'
```

The table with be something like this:

```
 id | January | February | March | ...
  1      P1        P2       P3
  2      P3        P1       P2
```

Doing a simple query like:

```
select * from Tarif where id = 1
```

I obtain

```
 id | January | February | March | ...
  1      P1        P2       P3
```

My objective is to change the query to something like:

```
select getMonth('2021-01-04') from Tarif where id = 1
```

and obtain that 'P1'.

It seems this this would be something easy to do, but this actually returns only what the function is returning: 'January'

Thank you all!!

Comment: How are you adding the month in the query in PHP? A simple ``$query = 'select `'.getMonth('2021-01-04').'` from Tarif where id = 1'`` should work well in your case

Answer (score 2):

This requires either dynamic SQL or explicit logic:

```
select (case getMonth( . . .)
            when 'January' then january
            when 'February' then february
            . . .
        end) as tarif
from tarif
where id = 1;
```

Note:  this is cumbersome because you have a poor data model.  You should really be storing the values in separate *rows*, with three columns:

```
id      monthname     tarif
```

Then you could just use:

```
select *
from tarif_good
where id = 1 and monthname = . . .;
```

Also, writing your own function to extract the month is a bit silly when [`monthname()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) already does this -- and it respects the internationalization settings for a wide variety of languages.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I think I'll listen to you and rearrange the table. It will be a bit heavy, but it will be worth it.

Again, thank you very much for your help. :DD